# i want to get Instagram profile total followers and following and post get this error 429 Too Many Requests on laravel

Tags: laravel, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get Instagram profile total followers and following and post get this error" `429 Too Many Requests` on Laravel.

[image]

I need for it to show my users profile information on their account page on my website. I tried it, but I didn't get the profile json data.

Here I send my route view and controller.

1. routes/web.php

```
Route::get('instagram', 'InstagramController@index');
```

2. app/Http/Controllers/InstagramController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
class InstagramController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Get the index name for the model.
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $items = [];
        if($request->has('username')){
     $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
     $url = sprintf('https://www.instagram.com/%s/media', $request->input('username'));
         $response = $client->get($url);
         $items = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['items'];
        }
        return view('instagram',compact('items'));
    }
}
```

3. resources/views/instagram.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel 5 Instagram API tutorial with example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Laravel 5 Instagram API tutorial with example</h2><br/>
        <form method="GET" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Instagram Username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Instagram Feed</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th width="200px;">Id</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Total Likes</th>
                        <th>Total Comments</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if(!empty($items))
                         @foreach($items as $key => $item)
                           <tr>
                            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['id'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['code'] }}</td>
                            <td><img src="{{ $item['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] }}" style="width:100px;"></td>
                            <td>{{ isset($item['location']['name']) ? $item['location']['name'] : '' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['likes']['count'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['comments']['count'] }}</td>
                           </tr>
                          @endforeach
                        @else
                           <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">There are no data.</td>
                           </tr>
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you asking how to avoid the limit set by instagram on their servers ? because the answer is "you can't". What you can do is cache some result so you dont need to fetch them again in the near future Or do it client side so you dont share the limit of all your users with your server.

Comment: i means when i hit this url https://www.instagram.com/actor.juwel/?__a=1 on browser it send all data but when i hit same url by API it don't send me anything it's say "429 Too Many Requests "

Comment: i do curious, is this 429 happens all the time on your laravel app or is it intermittent? if its the later, basically as the error said, you requested stuff too much please take a break. you have the option to cache instagram's response on laravel side so you didnt request stuff all the time.

Comment: everytime it's show when i search people username , if still need cache  then please tell me how can i do that